# Handling time-zone between client and server for date-only DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-web-api, timezone, utc

I have a custom validation attribute in my ASP.NET Web API application that checks if the date is in the future or not (dates in the future are not allowed). Here's the code:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        var date = (DateTime)value;
        if (date != null)
        {
            if(date.Date > DateTime.UtcNow.Date)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName), new[] { validationContext.MemberName });
            }
        }
    }

    return ValidationResult.Success;
}
```

I can't figure out how to make the comparison so it works for all time-zones. Using `DateTime.UtcNow` is not the solution, because if the client and the server are in the same timezone, in the hours close to midnight, the date will be the day after. And, of course `DateTime.Now` wouldn't work for other time-zones. So, what's the solution?

**Update:**

In my `WebApiConfig.cs` file, I have this code to set the `DateTimeZoneHandling` to `Utc`:

```
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
};
```

This will format the date in the JSON response like this: "2018-03-02T00:00:00Z".

And, all the DateTime values coming from the client will have their `Kind` property set to `Utc`. Then, I can compare the date with `UtcNow`, but now the problem is the date "2018-03-02T00:00:00Z" is displayed as March 1, 2018 in my browser, because it is converted to local time (UTC -5).

Comment: I am not sure about this but you might want to try:




DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            if (date.ToUniversalTime().Date > now.ToUniversalTime().Date)

Comment: @EdSF, Right now, for example, in my time zone it’s 11:45pm. If I select Mar 2, 2018 in my browser, and post it to the server, today’s UTC date on the server will also be Mar 2, 2018. So, the validation will pass. But, it shouldn’t, because today’s date is, actually, still Mar 1, 2018.

Comment: @RavirajPalvankar I’ll try it tomorrow, and let you know.

Comment: You should re-read you post and figure out why you believe there is an issue comparing two UTC date-only values. (Obviously you need convert local time to UTC first on client and server correspondingly, but it does not sound like you have problem with that part)

Comment: `in the hours close to midnight` no, they would still have the same time, the same date and it would be the *current* one.

Comment: In any case, since this is a Web API, just **don't** accept DateTime. Require a time with timezone and use DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime. The ISO8601 format contains a timezone element anyway.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I have tried it. So, no, the UTC date on the server would be different, in the hours close to midnight. Also, would you be able to provide some code to show me how I can use the DateTimeOffset in this case?

Comment: @ataravati no, the UTC date shouldn't be different unless the server's clock is set to the wrong time. UTC by *definition* has no offset. If one machine says 12:00+00 and another says 13:00+00 one of them is wrong. Which, btw, is why you *can't* trust the server clock to validate against future dates. Servers *are* set to the wrong time. Or the summer time settings are wrong. Even offsets are OK, clock skew means that the server and client may report slightly different times

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, they are different because the date coming from the client is not a UTC date. Look at the answer below. I need to convert the date to UTC before comparing it to UtcNow.

Comment: @ataravati that's not what you wrote in the question or the comment. Yes, you *do* have to convert. And after conversion they *shouldn't* be different unless there's misconfiguration.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, In the question and the previous comment I wrote the same thing. Please remember that I need the date part only of the datetime coming from the client. That makes it more complicated. The problem is, in the hours close to midnight, when I select tomorrow's date in my browser and send the date part only to the server, the `UtcNow.Date` on the server will also be tomorrow. So, the validation will pass, but it shouldn't because tomorrow is in the future. I hope I explained myself correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are only two viable approaches.

1. Convert to UTC on the *client* before sending the value to the server for comparison.
2. Try to determine the client's time zone id (or offset if just for a single point in time), and pass that from the client to the server.  The server can then use that information to do the conversion to UTC before comparison.

If you take neither of these options, passing only a client-local-time value to the server without any offset or time zone information, then there is no way to accomplish your goal.  There is no magic the server has about what the client's time zone may be.

Also, if you are comparing whole dates (ex `2018-03-02`, not `2018-03-02T00:00:00`), then you will need to decide which time zone is relevant for your use case.  For example, if you compare against UTC day, that is not going to work well for a business in Los Angeles unless they have aligned their business processes to UTC.

*Update per our chat:*

Since you only need to work with whole dates, then don't do any time zone conversions.  Make sure whatever date is chosen from your datepicker is exactly what is sent - rather than going through the `Date` object.  If your datepicker doesn't offer this value directly, then create it from the `Date` object - either manually or with a library like moment.js.  Don't call `.toISOString()` because in addition to ISO format, it will also assume you meant midnight local time and do a UTC conversion.

Also don't set any of JSON.Net's date settings - just use the defaults.

Comment: Thank you, Matt! The problem is on the client side, I only have a date-only datetime. The date is selected from a datepicker. I don't even care about the time. But, I do want to make sure the date is not in the future.

Comment: Can you please explain why this wouldn't work for a business in Los Angeles?

Comment: A business in Los Angeles is likely going to be operating based on US Pacific Time.  Their "day" does not stop and start at the same instant as the UTC day.  It starts and ends 8 hours earlier during standard time and 7 hours earlier during daylight saving time.

Comment: I can convert the date to UTC on the client side before sending to the server. There's no problem with that, but in order to do that, I'll have to set the `DateTimeZoneHandling` to Utc, and then the dates coming form the server to the client will be considered as UTC and will not be displayed correctly in the browser.

Comment: If you mean in your JSON settings, you don't need to set that.  Just ensure you use the ISO 8601 format with the trailing `Z`, such as given by the `.toISOString()` function on a JS `Date` object.  On the other side, make sure you are setting `DateTimeKind.Utc` on your .net `DateTime` objects and the resulting `Z` will appear correctly - which when you load back into a JS `Date` object it will all work correctly.

Comment: OK, this is kind of confusing. I'm going to update my question with more code, so you can help me with code. Thanks!

Comment: Also, since you only ask the client for the whole date, then likely you should interpret that as from start of that date to just before the start of the next date - in their local time.  Since you only care that the date is not in the future, just pass the start of date. As an example, if your user is in Pacific Time, and they pick `2018-03-02`, you would interpret that as `2018-03-02T00:00:00-08:00 to 2018-03-03T00:00:00-08:00`, which converted to UTC is `2018-03-02T08:00:00Z to 2018-03-03T08:00:00Z`. Send the `2018-03-02T08:00:00Z` to the server to compare against `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Comment: So, you're asking me to send two dates?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166130/discussion-between-matt-johnson-and-ataravati).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var date = (DateTime)value;
var utcDate = date.ToUniversalTime();
```

and than compere like this:

```
if(utcDate .Date > DateTime.UtcNow.Date)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, but how do I test it to make sure it also works if the client is in a different timezone?

Comment: This is not a good approach if running on a server, because it assumes that the `date` is in terms of the server's local time zone.

Comment: @MattJohnson, that's what I was thinking too. I doubt this will resolve the issue with the hours close to midnight. Do you have a solution? Please also read my most-recent comment on the OP. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**var timezoneOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();** - You can get this information from client to server (any web API call)

With the help of timezoneoffset details you can achiele the same. Here in my case i converted UTC DateTime to my client local datetime in Server side.

**DateTime clientDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow - new TimeSpan(timezoneOffset / 60, timezoneOffset % 60, 0);**