# C# OdataV4 Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext handle Timezone

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, odata

As stated in the title, i need to know how i can set the timezone to use in an OdataV4 Client.

In our Database we are storing DateTime-Values as GMT+1 since ever.

[image: DataBase]

For quite some time we were using a WebApi which was working on OdataV3.
As long as we were on OdataV3 we hadn't had issues related to TimeZones.

After switching to OdataV4, we are now facing some real, almost showstopping issues regarding the fact, that even if we set the `TimeZone` on the server to GMT+1, the client is now converting DateTimes to UTC.

This is the output from the Server:

[image: WebApiOutput]

As you can see, the times are identical. The +02:00 is related to summertime!
Now for whatever reason, the client displays this timestamp while debugging:

[image: Debug]

I was trying to find a method, which tells the DataServiceContext to not use UTC but couldnt find any. The closest i got was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49062859/handling-time-zone-between-client-and-server-for-date-only-datetime) but it seems not applicable to me.

There is quite a lot code, dealing with DateTimes and we cannot afford to refactor this all.
Also switching the Server back to UTC is not an option since every application has to be adjusted then.

**Question**

How can i set the `DataServiceContext` or an impacting component (JsonSerializer f.e.) to a TimeZone of my choice?

Comment: Please update your question with an example of the JSON (DTO) object that is being sent to the client, also are there multiple consumers in different timezones.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the client side to automatically translate ALL DateTimeOffsets into a DateTime in a specific timezone.

Comment: @lokusking Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @Alex Unfortunately not yet. Tbh i begin to think to fork the Odata-Repo and compile it myself

Answer (score 0):

First thing that I check is that the OData configuration is set to UTC on the *server*, the following is a standard Registration method I use in my OData v4 APIs, I'll leave the other entries in there to help you identify where in the pipeline to implement the call to `SetTimeZoneInfo`

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // To enable $select and $filter on all fields by default
    config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);
    config.SetDefaultQuerySettings(new Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.DefaultQuerySettings() { EnableCount = true, EnableExpand = true, EnableFilter = true, EnableOrderBy = true, EnableSelect = true, MaxTop = null });

    config.AddODataQueryFilter(new EnableQueryAttribute());
    config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

    // Set the timezone to UTC
    config.SetTimeZoneInfo(System.TimeZoneInfo.Utc);

    // Register the odata routes and other config
    ...
}
```

The above code is specifying UTC for all DateTimes that do not specify a timezone. The following variations show how you could set other timezones:

```
config.SetTimeZoneInfo(System.TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
config.SetTimeZoneInfo(System.TimeZoneInfo.Local);
config.SetTimeZoneInfo(System.TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time"));
```

If you wanted to affect the serialiser directly then you will need to register your own customised `ODataSerializerProvider` as the OData v4 framework uses this to deserialise the http request. That can be pretty involved, so try the simple option first.

Comment: Thx for your reply. Your solution is exactly what i do **not** want. Now every client has to be tought to use UTC. This is nonsense if you dont work international. What im basically looking for, is a way to tell the Client to not deserialize DateTimes as UTC.

Comment: What I was illustrating is how to set the timezone, I apologise for not inserting your timezone into the solution, I have updated the solution to highlight how to set a specific timezone.

Comment: Yeah... Anyway thx for your help. Im Still looking to get a solution for the Client, and not for the Server...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a workaround that could perhaps solve your issue:

It does not override deserialization but it fixes the dates by modifying the response.

The response is deserialized to UTC by default, and this will convert all DateTime objects to the local timezone(you can modify the code to change to any timezone you want). I assume your server and clients are in the same timezone.

You can set the server timezone to whatever you want, but I assume it will be +1 (most likely local).

```
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public class YourDataServiceContext: DataServiceContext
    {

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected YourDataServiceContext(Uri uri) : base(uri)
        {
            //add any code if you need here
            Configurations.ResponsePipeline.OnEntityMaterialized(ConvertDatesToLocalZone);
        }

        private void ConvertDatesToLocalZone(MaterializedEntityArgs obj)
        {
            var entity = obj?.Entity;
            if (entity == null) return;
            var props = entity.GetType()
                .GetProperties()
                .Where(it =>
                    it.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime)
                    || it.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?));

            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                //get value and check if it isn't null
                var value = prop.GetValue(entity);
                if (!(value is DateTime oldValue)) continue;

                //check if property has setter
                var setMethod = prop.SetMethod;
                if (setMethod == null) continue;

                //convert to local time
                value = oldValue.ToLocalTime();

                //set the new value
                setMethod.Invoke(entity, new[] { value });
            }
        }
    }
```