# how to set JSON ISO-8601 Datetime format timezone

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc

The situation is our c# mvc API return datetime to json format. The json datetime is ISO-8601 (UTC: 2020-04-22T18:30:30Z, Timezone 2020-04-22T18:30:30Z-05:00).

Our server is in timezone 05:00, we convert datetime by server timezone. Clients are worldwide, they pull API datetime. One client in timezone -07:00, they get the datetime value in 05:00 timezone with -07:00.

Question:
1. how can we set json convert timezone? That all clients will get the same ios-8601 value with -05:00 with server timezone
2. how to get client browser timezone? From request header?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possile to store UTC DateTime? If yes, then see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49062859/handling-time-zone-between-client-and-server-for-date-only-datetime

Comment: I would make us of moment.js : https://momentjs.com/timezone/