# string to Date object js

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, heroku, timezone

I'm trying to find out how to transform a string to a Date object in js, keeping the same time as written in the string ex.

i have this string

```
var time = "2021-01-20T17:30:00"
```

and i'm posting this variable from my website to my nodejs server running on Heroku.

The thing is, i want to work with the date object properties like time.getHours(), time.getMinutes() etc.. but the timezone of the server is different, precisely 1 hour after the timezone where i will be using the app, so if a create a new Object from this string, it goes forward 1 hour.
I'd like to keep the same date and time of the string, independently of where the server is, as i will be using this website only in my country (i can subtract one hour but what if i change the server?).

If i just send the string back it's fine, but i can't access the Date properties like this.

Can you point me in the right direction to accomplish this? make a new Date object that represents the same time as the string i use to create it? i can't find what i'm looking for.

Knowing the timezone i will be using this thing in, how can i create a Date object with the said timezone instead of the server' s one

Thanks

Comment: [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49074501/12485639). It's a C# question but still relevant to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's what i was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass it to a date object

```
    var time = "2021-01-20T17:30:00";
    var dt = new Date(time);
    console.log(dt);//Wed Jan 20 2021 17:30:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
```

the you can

```
    dt.getMonth()
    dt.getHours()
```

Comment: I did like that, what happens is if i work on localhost it's OK. When push the code to the server if i run dt.getHours() it gives back 18:30:00, not 17:30:00... BTW while i was writing my question i came up with an idea and checked if it was possible, turns out it is... i have forced Heroku to use the same timezone as mine with this command: heroku config:add TZ="Europe/Berlin". Thank you for your quick reply

Comment: based on your server you can alsways do +1 // to add time

Comment: Yes, i was thinking... what if i change server

Comment: @J0mk - Are you doing `console.log(dt)` like shown here?  If so, indeed you could get different results because that behavior is not defined by spec.  Shown here is the equivalent of `console.log(dt.toString())` (local-time based), but some implementations will do the equivalent of `console.log(dt.toISOString())` (UTC based).  Either way though, the results of `getMonth` and `getHours` would be the same.  I can elaborate more if you edit your question to fully show how you're using it and not just the string.

Answer (score 0):

In the front end create a new date, pass your time into that date, and then send the data that comes from from the `Date` methods to the backend.

(Also, I find it best practice to use `let` or `const` instead of `var` due to leaking issues with global variables.)

```
const time = "2021-01-20T17:30:00";
const dateTime new Date(time);

const dataToSend = {
  hours: dateTime.getHours(),
  minutes: dateTime.getMinutes(),
  // Any other data you want to send away
};

// Send dataToSend to your backend server
```

This will make it so that the date is already saved in your own timezone before you send it to the backend.

Comment: I don't think i can send the Date object back in a JSON as i need right now.

Comment: @J0mk I just edited my answer and it should work now.